# How to build Alexa auto SDK inside the AOSP setup

Tags: android-source, alexa-skills-kit

Trying to build the Alexa auto SDK 4.2 on inside the AOSP setup, but still unable to configure Alexa build inside the AOSP. are we need to write android bp file for all the modules ?

How it can build Alexa using AOSP build tools.

Answer (score 0):

While the Alexa Auto SDK is available to all developers through GitHub, developer support is only available to select automotive partners.
https://github.com/alexa/aac-sdk

For more information or questions on how to access developer support, please contact us using the form at the bottom of the Alexa Auto SDK developer console page.
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service/alexa-auto-sdk